# How to scroll through multiple TkLabels in Ruby/Tk

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

I want to scroll through successive numbers using a scrollbar.
I have managed to do this by changing a scrollable listbox that is big enough to only display one number at a time, but I was wondering if it is possible to set the scrollbar to a textvariable or something in order to make the listbox just TkLabels.

Here is my code so far:

```
require 'tk'
require 'tkextlib/tile'

root = TkRoot.new
$l = TkListbox.new(root) {height 1; width 2; 
        yscrollcommand proc{|*args| $s.set(*args)} }.grid :column => 0, :row => 0, :padx => 50, :pady => 10
$s = Tk::Tile::Scrollbar.new(root) {orient 'horizontal'; 
        command proc{|*args| $l.yview(*args)}}.grid :column => 0, :row => 1, :sticky => 'ew'
sz = Tk::Tile::SizeGrip.new(root).grid :column => 1, :row => 1, :sticky => 'se'
TkGrid.columnconfigure root, 0, :weight => 1
TkGrid.rowconfigure root, 0, :weight => 1

(0..10).each {|i| $l.insert 'end', "#{i}"}

Tk.mainloop
```

Comment: Sounds like a spinbox would be an appropriate widget.

Comment: Indeed, a spinbox would be the first thing to look at. Or a scale, and very possibly, a combobox.